# Can we execute a SQL like query using User defined Manager in Django?

Tags: django

Below is my model details

```
class QuesManager(db.Manager):
    def with_counts(self):
        from django.db import connection
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute("""
            SELECT Q.question, Q.title, Q.qid, V.up_qid, V.down_qid
            FROM Question Q, Votes_ques V
            WHERE Q.qid=V.qid
            ORDER BY 3 DESC""")
        result_list = []
        for row in cursor.fetchall():
            p = self.model(question=row[0], title=row[1], up_vote=row[2], down_vote=row[3])
            result_list.append(p)
        return result_list

class dummy(db.Model):
    obj = QuesManager()

class Question(db.Model):
    userid = db.CharField(max_length=50)
    posted = db.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    question = db.TextField(max_length=500)
    qid = db.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title = db.TextField(max_length=80)
    tags = db.ManyToManyField('Tags')

class Votes_ques(db.Model):
    qid = db.ForeignKey('Question')
    up_qid = db.IntegerField()
    down_qid = db.IntegerField()

from mysite.answers.models import dummy
from mysite.answers.models import Votes_ques
from mysite.answers.models import Question
```

Does, `Vote =  dummy.obj.all()` will give all result set of the query inside the QuesManager class. Anyone have any idea on this...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you're simply looking for this:

```
questions = Question.objects.all()
for question in questions:
    votes = question.votes_ques_set.all()
```

Comment: Hi, I have one doubt. How to combine both the objects (question and votes) correspondingly into a single object and finally into list of objects.

Comment: Hi WoLpH,

Yes, but how to combine both questions and votes, because I need to send this from my view to the html file. I mean, I am expecting something similar to a result set in the form of list, so that I can send it to my html file, where I will be using it.

Below is the part of my code

 args=dict(Questions=questions)
 t = loader.get_template('main.html')
 c = Context(args)
 return HttpResponse(t.render(c))

Here, Questions should contain the question object and the corresponding vote object joined together as a single object. Is this possible in Django? Please advise!!

Comment: So, once if that is possible, then in my main.html file, I will be having a code like
 {% if Questions %} 
   {% for item in Questions %}
     <hr/> 
     <form name="vote" method="GET" action="./votequestion">
     </h4> <b> Question</b>:{{item.qid}} </h4><br/>
     </h4> {{item.question}} </h4>
     <button name="up_vote" type="submit" value="Vote up">Vote up</button>x {{item.up_vote}}
     <button name="down_vote" type="submit" value="tagname">Vote down</button>x {{item.down_vote}}
   {% endfor %}
 {% endif %}

Comment: If this is not possible is there any way around to get the same thing. I basically need to display all the question object and its corresponding vote object.

Comment: @Prabakaran Subramanian: you can use `question.votes_ques_set.all` in a template aswell. But you can also do it the other way around. For every `Votes_ques` object you can get the `Question` with `qid`. So `some_votes_ques.qid` will give you the question.